VS1640105 When Copying Process
I am attempting to duplicate a process. When I attempt to use the “create copy of process” function, after a few seconds of churning, I receive the following error: VS1640105: Unrecognized value ‘New’ for property condition.value. Try validating rules for these values.
I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

This is an easy error code to search for. Do any of those solutions work? What have you tried? Have you done a Fiddler trace?

Hi @VivianeMori, Have you got a chance to check my suggestion below to check your work items rules? May I know if the answer can resolve your issue? Cheers.

Based on your description, I can reproduce the issue when I Create copy of process.

To reproduce the issue, I created a work item rule on the condition that A work item state changes to New and then removed the New states from the work item states.

For this, you may double check the work item rules of each work item type in your current process, especially check those rules related to work item states, so as to see if they are valid before duplicating a new copy.
